# How to treat region between conflict markers as comment?

Tags: comment, syntax

While resolving complex conflicts manually, I usually want emacs to treat conflict markers and region between them as comment, since it breaks major-mode's syntactic analysis (fontification, electric-indent, etc) :

```
<<<<<<< HEAD          <- comment
aaa
bbb
=======               <- comment
ccc                   <- comment
>>>>>>> brabrabrabra  <- comment
```

It seems possible to visually highlight them as comment with search-based fontification, but is it possible to treat them as comment not just visually but also syntactically ?

Comment: That would be very cool.  I guess you could try to modify the syntax table to add `<<<<<<<` and `>>>>>>>` as `comment-start` strings, but that might have unintended side effects.  Have you tried using `ediff-mode`?  The UI is a bit arcane, but it works pretty well once you get the hang of it, and it handles conflict blocks correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, but AFAIK noone has written the corresponding code.  This would need to be done via the `syntax-propertize-function`, to place appropriate `syntax-table` properties at the appropriate places.

It might be somewhat tricky to handle all cases, tho, such as when the conflict markers are within strings or comments.  But it's definitely worth a try and I'd welcome a patch to `smerge-mode` to provide that functionality.

Comment: Interestingly there are programming languages with multi-line strings. In those languages the conflict markers are ambiguous. Most simple case: A full conflict zone is within one string. Is this the actual string contents or is it a conflict zone??

Comment: @Tobias I think it's no big deal: smerge-mode is only enabled when actually dealing with merge conflicts (during which I assume it's acceptable to see false positives), and is disabled the rest of the time.

Comment: Thanks, `syntax-propertize-function` worked! Here's a minimal solution I tried (no considerations for such false positives): https://gist.github.com/zk-phi/01e67291b5e43d0c2839bed3cc778906 .